# Evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1}\mathop{dx}\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^k}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

My original question was what is the condition for the following integral to converge:  $$\int_{-1}^{1}\mathop{dx}\left[\frac{1}{x^{2k}}-\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^k}\right].$$ I know $k>0$. By motivation of Dr. MV, the condition is simply $2k<1$. Now, my question is how do I evaluate the second part of the above integral, that is $$\int_{-1}^{1}\mathop{dx}\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^k},$$ for any $k<1/2$ and real $a$. Any idea?

Comment: HINT:  Only the first term of the integrand contains a singularity.  For what values of $k$ does the integral $\int_{-1}^1 x^{-2k}\,dx$ converge?

Comment: It should be $2k<1$. Do you have any idea how to evaluate the second integral?

Answer (score 3):

In general, for $a,k\in\mathbb R^\star$, we have

> $$I~=~\dfrac2{a^{2k}}\cdot~_2F_1\bigg(\dfrac12~,~k~;~\dfrac32~;~-\dfrac1{a^2}\bigg)~=~-\dfrac i{|a|^{2k-1}}\cdot B\bigg(-\dfrac1{a^2}~,~\dfrac12~,~1-k\bigg),$$

which, needless to say, does not say much. For starters, let $x=at$, and then use the [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) of the integrand. Afterwards, in order to obtain the first expression, expand the integrand into its own [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and reverse the order of summation and integration. As for the latter, a second $($trigonometric$)$ substitution of the form $t=\tan u$ is in order, to reduce the expression to a [Wallis integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals), whose relation to the $($ [incomplete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) $)$ [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is well-known. For $k\in\mathbb N^\star$ and $a=1$, we have

> $$I~=~\dfrac{A_{k-1}}{(2k-2)!!}~+~\dfrac1{2^{2k-2}}{2k-2\choose k-1}\dfrac\pi2,$$

where $A_{k-1}$ form [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A087547).

Comment: Solid answer and +1.  I'm sure you already know this, but ... one needs to be very mindful of the applicable integration limits when expanding the integrand in the binomial series.  When enforcing the substitution, $x\to ax$, the upper limit is now $1/a$. If $|a| \ge 1$ then the expansion is in terms of powers of $x^2$.  If $|a|<1$, however, then we must split the integral as $\int_0^1 {}\,dx+\int_1^{1/a} {}\,dx$.  In the first integral the expansion is in powers of $x^2$ whereas in the second integral the expansion is in reciprocal powers of $x^2$ (Laurent).

Comment: @Dr.MV: Yes, sadly, I am painfully aware of all these tedious details. The OP might not be, though, so thank you for your comment.

Comment: Yes, I was certain you were.  And you're quite welcome.  You're one of the "good guys" on this site. - Mark